# Lag function on a character column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to shift all the values in the zone column down by one, and then compare where the zone and the new zone_shift column differ, to get an idea when the animal transitioned from one zone to another. However, I already get stuck at the very first step...

Here is a part of my df:

```
time  zone

0.00  social
2.036 social
2.100 social
2.196 interzone
3.436 nest
2.468 nest
2.676 nest
2.708 nest
2.868 nest
3.204 nest
3.300 interzone
```

I used the following function:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(zone_shift = dplyr::lag(zone, n = 1, default = NA_character_))
```

However, the result I get is the following:

```
    time  zone         zone_shift
    0.00  social       NA
    2.036 social       social
    2.100 social       social
    2.196 interzone    NA
    3.436 nest         NA
    2.468 nest         nest
    2.676 nest         nest
    2.708 nest         nest
    2.868 nest         nest
    3.204 nest         nest
    3.300 interzone    interzone
```

For the rest of the df, none of the values in the column are actually shifted - zone and zone_shift columns are exactly the same, and sometimes a NA is introduced where shift should occur.

I would be super grateful for any help!
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lag function, but this works I think:

```
df$zone_shift <- c(NA, df$zone[-length(df$zone)])

df$match <- df$zone == df$zone_shift
```

Comment: @Anoushiravan R, @ xaitorx: What is the purpose of the NA in the first line of this solution?

Comment: @WBarker I don't know this is not my solution, I just edited the format of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you two columns with your time and zone variables intact, and the latter shifted down by one.

```
df2<-df %>%
 mutate(time=time,zone=lag(zone)) %>%
 na.omit()
```

Comment: hi, I need to keep the original zone column and just add one which is shifted by 1. This one only leaves me with one column which isn't shifted...